# How virbr0-nic is created?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

How can I create a virtual network interface like `virbr0-nic`? I am trying to find a way to create a NIC like `virbr0-nic` but everything which I can find on the Internet is how to create an interface attached to the physical interface like `eth0:0`. 
When I write

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      8000.525400e0af01   yes virbr0-nic
virbr1      8000.525400e8a6b1   yes virbr1-nic
                            vnet1
```

So `virbr0` is the bridge to which `virbr0-nic` is attached. So how are `virbr0-nic` and `vnet1` created?

Comment: usually that's associated with something like a bridge specific to a bit of software. What're you REALLY trying to do?

Comment: I have installed KVM and noticed that it created new NIC virbr0-nic. I am just wondering how can I create my own NIC such as this one.

Answer (score 10):

These are dummy devices. You can run

```
modprobe dummy
```

To create a network interface called `dummy0`.

If you want more than one device, you can create say 5 with

```
modprobe dummy numdummies=5
```

You can then control these devices like any other network device.

Give it a MAC address with

```
ip link set dummy0 address aa:aa:aa:bb:bb:bb
```

Give it an IP address with

```
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev dummy0
```

Add it to your existing bridge with

```
brctl addif virbr0 dummy0
```

Set it up, set it down, NAT off it, and so on.

Comment: This answers seems to be more correct than [the alternative](http://serverfault.com/a/516558/126423) but it lacks detail about just creating an interface that's equivalent of what KVM setups by default (virbr0-nic).

Comment: The poster of the question seems to understand what the bridge does and what the dummy device does, he just wanted to know how to create similar interfaces. You are welcome to improve the answer if you feel it could be better.

Answer (score 6):

The libvirt is using TUN device for this purpose. You can manually create this device by following command:

```
# /usr/bin/tunctl -t virbr0-nic
```

Answer (score 2):

`virbr0-nic` stands for Virtual bridge NIC.

It's basically a bridge between your physical Network Card and your Virtual Machine's virtual Network Card.

To manage bridged interface you can use the `brctl` command.
You can list all your bridged interfaces with

```
brctl show
```

and add or modify bridges accordingly to your needs. To create a new bridge use

```
brctl addbr <name>
```

where `<name>` will be your new bridge's name (as virbr0-nic).Then you can add interfaces to the bridge with

```
brctl addif <brname> <ifname>
```

You can refer to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/brctl) for additional information.

Comment: This actually doesn't tell about creating a new "virbr1-nic", just a new "virbr1" whose interface to be set ("virbr1-nic") is implied to exist previously.

Comment: I don't think it is a bridge between physical and virtual either.  I have to do masquerading between virbr0 and the physical for packets to get routed.

Comment: Sorry, but `virbr0-nic` is *not* a bridge. It is a dummy device that exists only to provide a MAC address for the bridge: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444863/8928

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear exactly which types of devices `virbr0-nic` and `vnet1` are in your setup. There are a few types of virtual devices which can be useful to include in a bridge, some of which can be created using the `ip` command.

One kind of virtual devices is `veth` which creates pairs of connected virtual Ethernet interfaces.

```
ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
```

In this example `veth0` and `veth1` are arbitrary interface names that I came up with for the example. This method can for example be useful if you want to move one of the two interfaces to a different networking namespace.

Another kind of virtual interface is `vlan` where you create a single virtual Ethernet interface attached to a specific 802.1q tag on a physical interface:

```
ip link add link eth0 name eth0.10 type vlan id 10
```

There is a man page with information about even more types of virtual interfaces which can be created with the `ip` command. The name of the man page depends on which version you have installed, I have seen it named `ip-link` or just `ip`.

Additionally if you are using any virtualization there are virtual interfaces connecting host and VM. The specifics of those depend on the virtualization solution you are using.

Answer (score 1):

but i don't have this /usr/bin/tunctl -t virbr0-nic
i thing that is installed from cockpit and i can't find a delete option when i will use a virtual machine is it fine when it exist but for networking with systemd-networkd i have many problems with it.
Cockpit will use Network-Manager and the configuration files from it. after the installation my network is going down all devices and applications goes up with many fails.

If you check the ‘ifconfig -a’ after a fresh install of RHEL/CentOS 6,7 system, you would find the interfaces virbr0 name. Here is an example from freshly installed CentOS 7 system.

```
ifconfig -a
```

....

```
virbr0: flags=4099[UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST]  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:d5:f2:0c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098[BROADCAST,MULTICAST]  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:d5:f2:0c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

What is virbr0 interface
The virbr0 bridge interface is created by libvirtd’s default network configuration. libvirtd is the service which provides a basis for the host to act as a hypervisor. So in case you are not using xen virtualization, you can either prevent libvirtd’s default network from being activated on boot, or you could prevent libvirtd itself from activating on boot. The former will prevent any VM guest attached to libvirtd’s default network from having network connectivity and the latter would prevent VMs from running at all. Which is fine if you are not using it.
Disable libvirtd default network

1. You can disable libvirtd’s default network temporarily using the virsh command. This will not persist across reboot.

   ## virsh net-destroy default
2. To permanently disable the libvirtd default network from being created at boot:

   ## virsh net-autostart default --disable

Remove libvirtd default network
To permanently remove the libvirtd default network:

```
virsh net-undefine default
```

To permanently disable the libvirtd service from starting at boot on RHEL5 and RHEL6:

```
chkconfig libvirtd off
```

To permanently disable the libvirtd service from starting at boot on RHEL7:

```
systemctl disable libvirtd.service
```